# Conditional midnight gridlines in Altair gantt chart

Tags: altair, gantt-chart

I'm new to altair and I'm trying to set up an interactive gantt-chart, that displays booking times for rooms. With this code I achieve - content wise - the desired output:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'roomno': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'date_start': pd.to_datetime(['2023-04-04 08:00:00', '2023-04-04 12:00:00', '2023-04-05 08:00:00']),
                   'date_end': pd.to_datetime(['2023-04-04 14:00:00', '2023-04-04 18:00:00', '2023-04-05 14:00:00'])})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('date_start', axis = alt.Axis(grid = True)),
    x2='date_end',
    y='roomno'
).interactive()

chart

# I tried this to no avail: 
x=alt.X('date_start', axis = alt.Axis(grid = alt.condition(alt.datum.date_start == '00:00:00', 
                                                               if_true=alt.value('solid'), 
                                                               if_false=alt.value('dashed'))))
```

[image]

I'd like to improve styling to distinguish between days, and tried to add a `mark_rect()`-layer with alternating colors. It worked (somewhat-ish) but interfered when I used `color` in `mark_bar()`, which is why I'm looking for alternatives.

Now I'd like to modify the gridlines to distinguish between days (e.g. solid line at midnight, dashed line each hour). I looked at `alt.Condition()` though I am not sure this is what should be used.

I found this documentation: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#example-conditional-axis-properties-and-multi-line-axis-label which somehow tests the axis-properties
but I fail at translating this to altair and google and my SO-screen did not help me so far. Can anyone help and point me to the right direction - thx?
(I do have the restriction to use altair v4).

Comment: I think you should target `gridDash` instead of `grid` parameter. You could try with an ExprRef instead of a condition (same syntax as `expr` in 5.0 https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#expressions). You could also try using `alt.ConditionalAxisNumberArray` directly, but I'm not sure of the syntax on the top of my head. The simplest way might be to turn off the gridlines and use `mark_rule` to create grids where you need them.